# Android Lib to password-protect a Mifare Classic 1k Tag (with NDEF message)

Tags: android, nfc

I'd like to know if someone knows an open source lib that allows me to password-protect a Mifare 1k NFC tag that contains an arbitrary NFC message. I know this can be done, but it boils down to doing a lot of raw byte manipulation which is too low level for me.

Comment: What do you mean with arbitrary NFC message? Do you mean NDEF message? And i guess with password-protected Mifare 1K you mean that you want to change the keys of the Mifare sectors. Do you want to make it read or write protected or both?

Comment: I would like to know both variants. Cant understand how to change Ndef on/off password and how to set those passwords(